# Why should I use something other than Parallels

Tags: macos, windows, parallels-desktop

I am looking to use [Master Genealogist](http://www.whollygenes.com) on my Mac Pro with Parallels. Does anyone have experience using this program for Windows on a Mac? Any suggestions for a better setup than Parallels?

Comment: It would be helpful to better understand why Parallels isn't meeting your needs in order to suggest something that is *better*.

Answer (score 2):

You might find an easier solution in [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/) because it doesn't require a complete instance of the Windows Operating System.  I don't know that Master Geneologist is tested, but it would be worth trying. The Codeweavers community is very helpful and supportive of new software packages.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a Mac Pro I guess you have a big hard drive. Why not setting up [**Boot Camp**](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/)?
You sure can't go wrong with it, everything should work fine when you boot in Windows.

Other than that, I used to have Parallels, but I switched to **VMware Fusion**. I think they're pretty much comparable, I just like more the fact that Fusion is less obtrusive than Parallels.